# ncursesw functions not declared

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, archlinux

I need to use ncurses with unicode support, so I included the following line to my .c file.

`#include <curses.h>`

In my makefile I'm using -lncursesw as a flag. When calling functions like get_wch(), it tells me "implicit declaration of function". I'm on Arch Linux so I installed ncurses with pacman -S ncurses. In /usr/include I can find cursesw.h, but it doesn't have functions like get_wch() declared. Under /lib I can find libcursesw.so, so what's the matter?

Comment: Try installing the ncursesw (wide) package

Comment: Do not *describe* the code and error message. Instead, add the code (in the form of [mcve]) and error message (exact!) into the question post. See [ask].

Comment: Is there `/usr/include/ncursesw/`?

Answer (score 2):

`-lncursesw` is a *linker* flag, and by itself is not enough to enable wide char support. You should also add the *compiler* flag `-I/usr/include/ncursesw`. Without this your `#include <curses.h>` will end up including `/usr/include/curses.h` instead of `/usr/include/ncursesw/curses.h`

If you want a more standard way to find out required linker and compiler flags, you can use `pkg-config`. See the difference between those:

```sh
$ pkg-config ncurses --cflags --libs
-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -lncurses -ltinfo

$ pkg-config ncursesw --cflags --libs
-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -I/usr/include/ncursesw -lncursesw -ltinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<curses.h>`, read the header file to see which definition you prefer using:

```
/* 
 * With XPG4, you must define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED, it is redundant (or 
 * conflicting) when _XOPEN_SOURCE is 500 or greater.  If NCURSES_WIDECHAR is   
 * not already defined, e.g., if the platform relies upon nonstandard feature   
 * test macros, define it at this point if the standard feature test macros 
 * indicate that it should be defined. 
 */
#ifndef NCURSES_WIDECHAR
#if defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED) || (defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && (_XOPEN_SOURCE - 0 >= 500))
#define NCURSES_WIDECHAR 1
#else  
#define NCURSES_WIDECHAR 0
#endif
#endif /* NCURSES_WIDECHAR */
```

(just `NCURSES_WIDECHAR` should be enough).  This is summarized in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h2-ALTERNATE-CONFIGURATIONS).

If you read `cursesw.h`, you might notice that it is for the C++ binding.

As suggested in another answer, you can get some help from the pkg-config program.  However, that gives different results for Arch Linux:

```
$ pkg-config ncurses --cflags --libs
-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -lncursesw 
$ pkg-config ncursesw --cflags --libs
-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -lncursesw
```

That is, the Arch Linux packager has equated the two configurations of ncurses; both selections in `pkg-config` use the `ncursesw` library.  The Arch Linux package does have a `libncurses.so`, but that is only a text-file telling the linker to use `libncursesw.so`.  Because of the way it is packaged, on Arch Linux it makes no difference which library you use.

(offhand, combining `_GNU_SOURCE` and `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` is incorrect, probably not from any distribution's packaging system, because the former was deprecated in ncurses [five years ago](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20160806)).

Comment: I tried defining _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED or NCURSES_WIDECHAR or defining _XOPEN_SOURCE with a value bigger than 500, but it still doesn't work.