# ncurses get_wch() function undeclared

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, curses, widechar

I try to check the output of the `get_wch` function from the ncurses library, on Archlinux install.

But when I call the function, I got this GCC error:

> main.c:6:15: warning: implicit declaration of function "get_wch";

I linked the lib like my GCC command-line suggest:

```
gcc main.c -lncursesw -o exec
```

I have also check that ncurses is installed:

> core/ncurses 6.2-1 [installed]
> multilib/lib32-ncurses 6.2-1 [installed]

And I see the header generated at the lib compile time that allow me to use "widec" functions, when I list header files in the "usr/include" directory.

```
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    int test = 0;
    int result = get_wch(&test);
    printf("Caractère : {} / Function code : {}\n", test, result);
    endwin();
return 0;
}
```

I don't understand how to use this lib. And the available "documentation" seems to play against me...

Comment: The order of arguments on the command line matters. Always put libraries *last*, after any source or object files.

Comment: It sucks... But it's done and I have the same problem. Here is my new gcc line: "gcc main.c -lncursesw -o exec"

Comment: [This recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59971200/ncursesw-functions-not-declared) have a possible work-around.

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to compile, now. That's a sticky trick, but it works. Would you write the answer, or I did ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gcc *warning*

```
main.c:6:15: warning: implicit declaration of function "get_wch";
```

tells you that there is no function prototype for [**`get_wch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html).  X/Open Curses specified all of the *wide-character* functions conditionally (to avoid breaking old programs).  That's summarized in the [ncurses manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h2-ALTERNATE-CONFIGURATIONS):

> You must also enable the wide-character  features  in  the  header
> file  when  compiling  for  the  wide-character library to use the
> extended (wide-character) functions.   The  symbol  which  enables
> these features has changed since XSI Curses, Issue 4:
>
> - Originally,  the  wide-character  feature  required the symbol
>   **`_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED`**  but  that  was  only  valid  for  XPG4
>   (1996).
> - Later,  that was deemed conflicting with **`_XOPEN_SOURCE`** defined
>   to 500.
> - As of mid-2018, none of the features  in  this  implementation
>   require  a  **`_XOPEN_SOURCE`**  feature greater than 600.  However,
>   X/Open Curses, Issue 7 (2009) recommends defining it to 700.
> - Alternatively,  you  can  enable  the  feature   by   defining
>   **`NCURSES_WIDECHAR`**  with  the caveat that some other header file
>   than curses.h may require a specific value  for  **`_XOPEN_SOURCE`**
>   (or a system-specific symbol).

The prototype for `get_wch` uses **`wint_t`** (an integer which can hold a "wide character" such as Unicode).  The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Routine-and-Argument-Names) lists these types which are used in the wide-character *ncursesw* library (and function prototypes): **`cchar_t`**, **`wchar_t`** and **`wint_t`**

If you want to use a function prototype using any of those types, your program should turn on the feature.  As mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59973188/4518274), defining **`NCURSES_WIDECHAR`** is simplest.